# csv to sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I have a big csv file which lists connections between nodes in a graph. example:

0001,95784
0001,98743
0002,00082
0002,00091

So this means that node id 0001 is connected to node 95784 and 98743 and so on.
I need to read this into a sparse matrix in numpy. How can i do this?
I am new to python so tutorials on this would also help.

Comment: What do you mean by '0001 is connected to 95784', in the terms of the matrix you want to have?

Comment: By this i mean that the node(id: 0001) has a directed link to node(id: 95784)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example using [lil_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html) (list of list matrix) of scipy.

> Row-based linked list matrix.
>
> This contains a list (`self.rows`) of rows, each of which is a sorted list of column indices of non-zero elements. It also contains a list (`self.data`) of lists of these elements.

```
$ cat 1938894-simplified.csv
0,32
1,21
1,23
1,32
2,23
2,53
2,82
3,82
4,46
5,75
7,86
8,28
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
from scipy import sparse

rows, columns = 10, 100
matrix = sparse.lil_matrix( (rows, columns) )

csvreader = csv.reader(open('1938894-simplified.csv'))
for line in csvreader:
    row, column = map(int, line)
    matrix.data[row].append(column)

print matrix.data
```

Output:

```
[[32] [21, 23, 32] [23, 53, 82] [82] [46] [75] [] [86] [28] []]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Any good resources for scipy that you can recommend?

Comment: One small question. The numbers in the csv are not the indices. they are Ids ie the file starts with 
0001001,9304045
0001001,9308122
0001001,9309097
0001001,9311042
0001001,9401139
0001001,9404151
0001001,9407087
0001001,9408099
0001001,9501030
0001001,9503124

So how do i convert these IDs to numerical indices, the ID server the purpose of just identifying nodes, they may be replaced by equivalent indices if they are unique.
How do I accomplish this. I know I can just make rows and columns as big as the largest ID but that seems wasteful as the nodes like with indices 0 - 1001 are wasted.

Comment: i understand your concern and i assume, there is no one best way to 'compress' your data to the relevant elements. it depends largely on your goal, what you want to do with the data later. e.g. you could use a 'mapping dictionary' which maps the actual ids to some smaller numerical values ...

Comment: If you do want to 'squeeze' your indices so that they start at 0 and go up in increments of 1 to some maximum, why not (1) sort them producing `sorted_ixs` (`sorted_ixs = ixs; sorted_ixs.sort()`), (2) `zip(sorted_ixs, range(len(sorted_ixs))` producing a list of pairs matching an index with a 'squeezed index', (3) use the list as a 'translation table' from old to new indices.

Comment: Actually this will also sort `ixs`, I think; use `sorted_ixs = ixs[:]` if you want to keep your unsorted `ixs` around.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an adjacency matrix, you can do something like:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
import csv
S = dok_matrix((10000,10000), dtype=bool)
f = open("your_file_name")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for line in reader:
    S[int(line[0]),int(line[1])] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in [Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), a pure python network/graphing package.

From the website:

> NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1,2)
>>> G.add_node("spam")
>>> print G.nodes()
[1, 2, 'spam']
>>> print G.edges()
[(1, 2)]
```