# Does the np.nan in numpy array occupy memory?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a huge file of csv which can not be loaded into memory. Transforming it to libsvm format may save some memory. 
There are many nan in csv file. If I read lines and store them as np.array, with np.nan as NULL, will the array still occupy too much memory ?
Does the np.nan in array also occupy memory ?

Comment: *Does the np.nan in array also occupy memory?* A `numpy` array is a homogeneous fixed-size record data structure, i.e. the same amount of memory is allocated for each of its elements (e.g. 4 bytes for `float32` and 8 bytes for `float64`). `numpy.nan` is simply represented by a special (reserved) bit pattern.

Comment: Numpy arrays are contiguous (assuming C ordering and no transpose) blocks of memory. No matter what you store on it, it will occupy space equivalent to its shape and data type. Scipy has sparse matrices that you could use to ignore nans.

Comment: You might find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938894/csv-to-sparse-matrix-in-python) helpful which constructs a sparse scipy matrix from a CSV.

Comment: `scikit-learn` does work with `(lib)svm`. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html.  But you'll need to read its docs to see whether that helps with your memory issues.

Answer (score 6):

When working with [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers) representations of numbers, non-numeric values (`NaN` and `inf`) are also represented by a specific binary pattern occupying the same number of bits as any numeric floating point value. Therefore, `NaN`s occupy the same amount of memory as any other number in the array.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know yes, nan and zero values occupy the same memory as any other value, however, you can address your problem in other ways:

Have you tried using a sparse vector? they are intended for vectors with a lot of 0 values and memory consumption is optimized

[SVM Module Scipy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

[Sparse matrices Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)

There you have some info about SVM and sparse matrices, if you have further questions just ask.

Edited to provide an answer as well as a solution

Comment: Which package should I use? The scipy ? Any examples ? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure the sparse vector will support xgboost. Because my goal is to train model on it.

Comment: Do not use the sparse matrix code unless your learning/training code explicitly says you can.  Some scikit-learn methods do.

Comment: I have sometimes used it to train a SVM using scipy, if you are interested in it I can look for my code and post it

Answer (score 3):

According to the getsizeof() command from the sys module it does. A simple and fast example :

```
import sys
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,np.nan,3])

x_size = sys.getsizeof(x)
y_size = sys.getsizeof(y)
print(x_size)
print(y_size)
print(y_size == x_size)
```

This should print out

```
 120
 120 
 True
```

so my conclusion was it uses as much memory as a normal  entry.

Instead you could use sparse matrices (Scipy.sparse) which do not save zero / Null at all and therefore are more memory efficient. But Scipy strongly discourages from using Numpy methods directly https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html  since Numpy might not interpret them correctly.

Comment: On my machine, this prints `108, 120, False`, because `x.dtype == np.int32`. To make this a useful example, you should use `1.0, 2.0, 3.0`, which will make the arrays have the same type

Comment: Okay, sorry. I didn't know that there might be a difference between machines for that example. But to be fair on my machine, it works like that. And furthermore `x.dtype == np.int64 `and analogously the datatype for `y ==np.float64` in my case