# Pandas NA values list

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to remove **b'NA'** from default pandas na_values. They are defined in **pandas._libs.parsers**. I did it by importing the list and:

```py
from pandas._libs.parsers import _NA_VALUES

disable_na_values = [b"NA"]
my_default_na_values = [
    item.decode("UTF-8") for item in _NA_VALUES if item not in disable_na_values
]

df = pd.read_excel(filepath, keep_default_na=False, na_values=my_default_na_values)
```

It works and now, after excel/csv is imported the cells with "NA" value are ignored (country code for Nambia).

However what I don't understand, why are this **na_values** as bytes? And where are they used?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624404/does-the-np-nan-in-numpy-array-occupy-memory

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see a list of byte strings is because you are importing the wrong variable.  You should use STR_NA_VALUES instead, which give you a set.  From this set you can easily remove the items you don't want by subtracting.  See below:

```
from pandas._libs.parsers import STR_NA_VALUES

disable_na_values = {"NA"}
my_default_na_values = STR_NA_VALUES - disable_na_values
```